# Setting the HTACCESS file to redirect all .cfm requests to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess rewrite rule that I wrote, that is supposed to take any requests that container index.cfm and redirect them to the index.php.

http://testsite.com/index.cfm/a/catalog.prodShow/vid/42110/catid/154

However, it is not redirecting this properly. If I just put in index.cfm (no rest of the url) it works fine, however, the moment the /a/... is added to it, it takes me to the 404 page.

How do I adjust my rule so that it works properly for ANY url that has index.cfm anywhere in it?

Here is my rule:

RewriteRule ^index.cfm$ /index.php [L,NC,R]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RewriteRule, the `^` and the `$` indicate the start and the end of the line. If you wish to match any index.cfm (like `/index.cfm/a/...` or `/sub1/sub2/index.cfm/...`) you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*index.cfm.*)$ /index.php?original_url=$1 [L,NC]
```

I added the original url as a parameter because you might need it to process the request and I removed the `R` flag to avoid loops.

Comment: I tried it verbatim, and it didnt seem to work. I put the R back in, and it did the trick! Thanks.